# Application get exit

Tags: android, android-webview

I am showing website inside fragment with webview,

On load oh website when I click on backpress button , my app get exit .

Here is my code :

```
webview.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    WebView webView = (WebView) v;

                    switch(keyCode)
                    {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        if(webView.canGoBack())
                        {
                            webView.goBack();
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
                            if (fragment != null) {
                                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
                                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                            }                       }
                        break;
                    }
                }               return false;
            }


        });
```

Comment: do u have any other view in stack?

Answer (score 1):

You should implement a function called:

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
         //write your code here
    }
```

Comment: I tried that but it gives me error ,  The method onBackPressed() of type Fragmentpage must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: you have to mention  @Override before the implementation of funtion. Have you done it?

Answer (score 0):

Your activity catch first time back button pressed. If you don't override `onBackPressed()` your app will close all time.